# WebAPI in python not running in the localhost

Tags: python-3.x, webapi

I am trying to run WebAPI in my localhost but showing errors. When I put the contents out of the function, the code runs and shows no error. But I want to put the contents inside the function. Can somebody help me to solve this problem? Below is my code written in python.

```
@app.route('/shops')
def get_shops():
    load_dotenv()

    home_url = os.environ['URL']

    session = HTMLSession()


    with open('allshopdata.json','w') as jsonfile:
        get_url = session.get(home_url)
        get_url.html.render(sleep=1)
        location = get_url.html.xpath('//*[@id="#####"]', first=True)

        all_shop_data = []


        for all_location_shop in location.absolute_links:
            get_shop = requests.get(all_location_shop)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(get_shop.text, 'html.parser')
            all_location_shop = soup.findAll('div', attrs = {'class':'shop_list'})
            
            for shop_list in all_location_shop:
                link = shop_list.findAll('h4')

                for shop_name in link:
                    links = shop_name.findAll('a')
                    for name in links:
                        shop_name = name.text
                        shop_code = name.get('href')
                        shop_data = {"shop": shop_name, "shop_number": int(shop_code)}
                        all_shop_data.append(shop_data) 
        json.dump(all_shop_data, jsonfile, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)

   
    return jsonify({"shops": all_shop_data})

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

app.run(port=5000)
```

And this is the error.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or
    there is an error in the application.</p>
```

Comment: As it stands, we probably can't reproduce this. Have you debugged?

Comment: You need to find and look at your app logs, to find the actual/exact error (starts with "Traceback"). That 500 error is usually the framework's default response when there is an error while running your route function .

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I debugged the whole program and finally solved my problem by making multiple functions.